# Взять следующий элемент ассоциативного массива на PHP

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть ассоциативный массив.

К примеру.

```
$foo = array('x'=>'x_val','y'=>'y_val','z'=>'z_val');
```

И есть цикл `foreach`.

```
foreach ($foo as $key=>$val){
    //Тут какая то логика
}
```

Нужно взять в текущей итерации следующий $val. Ну или `$key`.

Как можно этого добиться ?

Comment: а на последней итерации ? ОН вам нужен всегда или только при каких-то условиях?

Comment: @splash58 нет на последней не нужен.Можно сказать условие если не последний то взять, если последний можно возвротить 0 или `null`.

Comment: например сихронный индекс `$i=0;` до цикла и `print_r(array_slice($foo, ++$i, 1));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проще всего, будет использовать вспомогательный массив соответствий

```
$foo = array('x'=>'x_val', 'y'=>'y_val', 'z'=>'z_val');

$keys = array_keys($foo);
array_shift($keys);
$matches = array_combine(array_keys($foo), $keys + [-1 => null]);


foreach($foo as $k => $v){
    $nextKey = $matches[$k];
    print_r([$k, $nextKey]);
}
```

результат

```
Array(
    [x] => y
    [y] => z
    [z] => 
)
```

Однако, вообще стоит задуматься, что есть порядок ключей в ассоциативном массиве, и имеет ли он в целом смысл и гарантирован ли при обходе

Comment: Спасибо за решение, помогли

Comment: Кто это ответ минусовал?

Answer (score 1):

Через array_keys и array_search, но не сказал бы что это лучший способ (в комментариях получше способ есть)

```
$tmp = array_keys($foo); // ["1" => "x", "2" => "y" ...]
foreach ($foo as $key=>$val){
    $tmp_key = array_search($key, $tmp); //  узнаем ключ $tmp по которому хранится значение $key
    $nextKey = $tmp[$tmp_key + 1]; // следующий ключ
    $nextValue = $foo[$nextKey]; // следующее значение
    echo $nextValue; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [next](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.next.php)

```
$array = ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2, 'z' => 3];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $nextValue = next($array);
    // Что бы узнать ключ следующего значения, можно вызвать key($array);
    echo $value . ' ' . $nextValue . PHP_EOL; 
}


/*
Вывод:
1 2
2 3
3
*/
```

UPD: в комментариях подсказали, что этот пример работает только в PHP 7

UPD2: Вот версия, которая работает одинаково в PHP 5 и PHP 7

```
$array = ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2, 'z' => 3];

while ($key = key($array) !== null) {
    $value = current($array);
    $nextValue = next($array);

    echo $value . ' ' . $nextValue . PHP_EOL;
}


/*
Вывод:
1 2
2 3
3
*/
```

Comment: https://eval.in/946801

Comment: @splash58 PHP 7 работает как ожидалось https://eval.in/946805

Comment: так-то значения выводит, а не ключи

Comment: а, там _или_ было, да.

Comment: @teran Добавил в ответ по поводу ключа

Comment: в пхп 7 `foreach` не передвигает указатель текущего элемента, поэтому данный код будет зависеть от версии пхп

Answer (score 0):

Просто используй ключ на следующей итерации как предыдущий ключ, а к текущему ключу относясь как к следующему ключу.

```
$bOnce=false;//первую итерацию пропустить
$keyPrev;//инициируется в первой итерации
foreach($foo as $key=>$val){
 if(!$bOnce){
  $bOnce=true;
  $keyPrev=$key;
  continue;}
 $keyNext=$key;

 //тут ваши действия с предыдущим и следующим элементом

 $keyPrev=$keyNext;}
```